# Edit .phtml file without have to run setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, phtml, setup-upgrade

I'm running on Magento 2 version 2.1.7, but everytime i change my .phtml file content i need to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to see the change. I already set my magento 2 to developer mode

Comment: This will help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184927/35758

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/171385/42007

Answer (score 1):

You only need to run:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

to see changes of phtml files.

The command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` is used to deploy new modules.

Comment: yes i run those scripts too, but usually my phtml file changed always show right away after i edit it without having to run any script in terminal

Comment: I don't see how that is possible unless static content and cache was disabled or if you are reffering to Magento 1.X

Comment: No need of static content deploy . Only cache flush is more than enough

Answer (score 0):

Actually `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` is used when modules need to be upgraded.

For the case of change in `.pthml` files, if cache is enabled you must run `php bin/magento cache:clean`. This works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

**For phtml only cache command is enough**

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**No need of upgrade and static content deploy command**

Answer (score 0):

Use `php bin/magento`, then you'll find all commands with their use

[image]

So:

```
setup:upgrade : Upgrades the Magento application, DB data, and schema
```

And you need:

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the change without running any command, you should disable all the caches.